# How can I use LocalContext inside LaunchedEffect?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to obtain `Context` within a `LaunchedEffect`?
I need to call a certain function which needs the reference of `Context` object in order to execute.

I cannot use `LocalContext.current`, because:

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get context value in view builder context and then use it in `LaunchedEffect`:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
LaunchedEffect(context) {
    context
}
```